# Cannot update mysql with PDO when variable is a decimal

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having a problem trying to update a mysql record with PDO.  When values are integers they update just fine.  But if those same values are decimals they do not.  I have read about this a good amount, and it seems like making it the STR parameter type is the answer but I cannot get it to work.  here is my code:

```
$sth_g103 = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE teams SET losses=:new_losses_l, wins=:new_wins_l,  percent=:percent_l WHERE team_id = :loser_id");

$sth_g103->bindParam(':loser_id', $loser_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth_g103->bindParam(':new_losses_l', strval($new_losses_l), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth_g103->bindParam(':new_wins_l', strval($new_wins_l), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth_g103->bindParam(':percent_l', strval($percent_l), PDO::PARAM_STR);

$sth_g103->execute();
```

it updates them just fine if the last 3 variables are integers; but fails when decimals; can anyone help with this?

thanks, G

Comment: What data types are your columns?

Comment: if you mean the mysql table datatypes; they are set to "decimal 10.2 or 10,3); but I do not think that is the issue since it stores them fine when they are not decimals

Comment: Fails in what way? Does it store incorrect values, get an error?

Comment: basically it just does not update the columns in mysql; the columns just retain there old values; but if the input is not a decimal then it updates the mysql columns...

Comment: Please, add create table and example data.

Comment: Decimal values? PHP has no a such type. What do you mean by `decimal`?

Comment: ok sectus:  take the variable $new_losses_l; if it is set to 6 then it works fine; but if it is set to 0.5 it does not

Comment: and let me say that PHP handles decimals fine; maybe I am just using the wrong term?  an integer is an even number; so I am referring to 0.5 as a decimal; but that may be the wrong way to describe it.  Regarding 'create table"; the table already exists; so I am just updating records that are already present in the table...

Comment: Also, what is output of `strval`?

Comment: um the strval is something I have seen people use when trying to have PDO update mysql with a "non-integer"; so i used that trying to make it work; but it did not help any; it has something to do with using the STR parameter; and so the numbers need to be converted in that way or have quotes around them...

Comment: @gman_donster , ok. I'll repeat. Could you provide `show create` of your table, example data (from var_export), result of strval(from var_sump)? Please, put this information into the question.

Comment: Hello Sectus:  i got it output errors from PDO but there were no errors; but while doing this I noticed that the 4th variable is being update with a non-integer "percent_l" and so maybe the problem is not the non-integer input at all; I will be messing around with this to see if I can figure out why that one works and not the other two and I will let you all know… thanks so much,  G

Comment: Hello Guys: I finally figured out that the problem was totally unrelated to what I posted; I am sorry if I wasted anyone's time and I appreciate all of your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Guys: I finally figured out that the problem was totally unrelated to what I posted; I am sorry if I wasted anyone's time and I appreciate all of your help…

Basically there was a function "higher up in the stream" that was making it fail - and it had nothing to do with non-integers being entered; but because with this function they were always non-integers it really looked like that was the cause...